# refactor regex ruby code

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to get the resource name from a class name like:

> "SequelAdapter::UserGraph"

So I would want user in this case.

Currently I have this code which does work but is very ugly:

```
klass = object.class.to_s

if start = klass =~ /[::][A-Za-z]*Graph/
  finish = klass =~ /Graph/

  klass = klass[start + 1, finish - start - 1]
end
```

Can anyone suggest a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) solution:

```
object = SequelAdapter::UserGraph.new
/(?<klass>[A-Za-z]*)Graph/.match( object.class.to_s )[1]
klass # => "User
```

For [ruby-2.0](/questions/tagged/ruby-2.0), try as follows:

```
/(?<klass>[A-Za-z]*)Graph/ =~ object.class.to_s
klass # => "User
```

if you wish more exact [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp):

```
object = SequelAdapter::UserGraph.new
/(?<klass>[A-Z](?:[[[:alpha:]]])*)*Graph/ =~ object.class.to_s
klass # => "User
```

Answer (score 1):

try this out:

```
 klass = object.class.to_s.match(/(\w+)Graph$/).captures[0]
 klass
 => "User"
```